# parsing multidimensional js object in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a js object that looks like this:

`0: Object
   answer: Object
        answer1: "fweq"
        answer2: "qwef"
        answer3: "fqwef"
        answer4: "vrevwe"
   question: Object
        content: "<p>my content</p>"
        title: "test"
   type: Object
        type: "addmcq"`

I am trying to iterate and parse this in php. 
However its messing with my head.

My php looks like this:

```
$question = $_POST['data'];
$question = json_decode($question, true);
var_dump($question);
foreach($question as $q) {
    foreach($q as $item) {
        $type = $item['type'];  //Echoes the type correctly
            echo $item['content']; //Does nothing
            echo $item['answer1']; // Does nothing
            echo $item['answer2']; // --
            echo $item['answer3']; // --
            echo $item['answer4']; // --

    }
}
```

$type will echo out whatever is in the type object but $item['answer1'] will not.

**How can i iterate the answer array?**

heres the output of the var_dump(question):

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["question"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(48) "
                    test  
                    "
      ["content"]=>
      string(12) "<p>asetw</p>"
    }
    ["answer"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["answer1"]=>
      string(4) "fweq"
      ["answer2"]=>
      string(4) "qwef"
      ["answer3"]=>
      string(5) "fqwef"
      ["answer4"]=>
      string(6) "vrevwe"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "addmcq"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Once again look at your array structure. `var_dump($q, $item);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines should be

```
echo $item['question']['content'];// suggested by @zedd
echo $item['answer']['answer1']; 
echo $item['answer']['answer2']; 
echo $item['answer']['answer3']; 
echo $item['answer']['answer4'];
```

This is because all `answer1,answer2,...` are present inside `answer` index

Comment: this is correct, and also $item['question']['content'] for the first line

Comment: Thank u for this. I didnt see ir actually.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! :) It makes more sense to me after that.
I ended up removing the second foreach loop and your answer. works like a charm!